# How to determine if columns match in Excel?

Tags: excel, match, excel-formula

I have 4 columns I would like to match up to each other. last_nameDB, first_nameDB, last_name, first_name.  I would like to use a formula that will simply output yes or no if the last name and first names match.  Examples of data and desired output are below.

[image]

Desired output:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you like regular formulas, drag this one down:

```
=IF(AND(A2=D2, B2=E2), "Y", "N")
```

If you like [array formulas](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx), enter this one for the whole column:

```
=IF(A2:A12=D2:D12,IF(B2:B12=E2:E12,"Y","N"),"N")
```